# Lossless codec for bayer data

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, gstreamer, codec, lossless-compression

I'm working with lots of camera's which capture in BG bayer pattern natively.

Now, every time I record some data, I save it to the disk in the raw bayer pattern, in an avi container. The problem is, that this really adds up after a while. After one year of research, I have close to 4TB of data...

So I'm looking for a lossless codec to compress this data. I know I could use libx264 (with --qp 0), or huffYUV, dirac or jpeg2000, but they all assume you have RGB or YUV data. It's easy enough to convert the bayered data to RGB, and then compress it, but it kind of defeats the purpose of compression if you first triple the data. This would also mean that the demoasicing artefacts introduced by debayering would also be in my source data, which is also not too great. It would be nice to have a codec that can work on the bayered data directly.

Even more nice would be that the solution would involve a codec that is already supported by gstreamer (or ffmpeg), since that's what I am already using.

Answer (score 3):

A rather late suggestion, maybe useful for others..

It helps to deinterleave the Bayer pattern into four quadrants and then treat that image as grayscale. The sub-images (e.g. all red pixels in top left) have half the spatial resolution, but their pixels are more highly correlated. This leads to lower residuals from predictors using nearby pixels and therefore to better compression ratios.
I've seen this reach 2-3x lossless compression on 12-bit raw camera data.

Comment: just commenting to say that this doesn't make much difference for me (quantitatively, the median improvement is 1%; 5% smaller best case, 7% bigger worst case, over ~450 video frames).  e.g. encoding one original/raw Bayer patterned image as a lossless JPEG 2000 encoded image takes 42% of the original size (i.e. 2.4x compression) while the version having a channel in each quadrant was only 3% smaller for this image

Comment: Thanks for sharing your numbers. Yes, one downside is that the quadrant borders are poorly predicted discontinuities (costly to compress).
Another alternative would be to treat each 2x2 pattern as one half-resolution R,G,B pixel (to be passed to a conventional RGB codec). The other Bayer sample G2 (or better yet, G-G2) could be stored with a grayscale coder. That allows decorrelation across pixels *and* channels.

Comment: agreed about the borders, but I was hoping they'd occupy a small proportion of the pixels and hence wouldn't matter too much.  also, the images I happened to test with were mostly symmetric so there shouldn't have been much of a discontinuity

Comment: interesting "half res" pixel idea, do you know if the second green channel can be stored in the same file/stream (I'm new to the jpeg2000 format)?  I've tried with seperate files and it doesn't seem to help; I also tried a variant of storing the mean of the G channels in the RGB image, then a delta as greyscale, seems to save 7% for half my images, but am struggling with the maths of making this reversible (my naive version loses the LSB)

Comment: JPEG XL does support this ("extra channels"), not sure about J2K. Glad to hear mean+delta helps. For reversibility, I think both the mean and delta require an extra bit of precision - the mean is basically the sum interpreted as a fixed-point number with one fractional bit.

Answer (score 1):

If a commercial solution is ok, check out [Cineform](http://cineform.com/). I've used their sdk for a custom video compressor and it works great plus they have some great tools for processing the raw video.

Or if you prefer the open source route check out [Elphel JP4](http://wiki.elphel.com/index.php?title=JP4).

Comment: Reviving this answer since Cineform has been released as [open source](https://github.com/gopro/cineform-sdk).

Answer (score 0):

All I know about Bayer Patterns I learned from Wikipedia, but isn't conversion to RGB more of a deinterlacing than a tripling? Doesn't the resolution for red and blue go down by a factor of 4 and green by a factor of 2? If so, a lossless image compression scheme like lossless jpeg might be just the thing.

Comment: With a BG Bayer filter, you basically have 4 bits per pixel for green, 2bpp for blue and 2bpp for red, for a total of 8bpp. Now if you demosaic this to BGR, the result is typically 24bpp (8 per color), thus triple the amount of data. Indeed, the actual information is the same.

Comment: As most lossless video codecs I know about (HuffYUV, ffv1,..) only have a compression ratio of around 3, compressing the BGR version doesn't have any advantage over storing the raw Bayer data.
Compressing the bayer data as it were gray values, typically results in a compression ratio of around 2, and I reckon there has to be a better codec.
(why this comment char limit?)